# Why does it require an initial double click to run function, thereafter single click?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
// Quote Data
const data = {
  quotes: [{
    id: 1,
    "author": "Shakespeare",
    "source": "Julius Caesar",
    "quote": "Cowards die many times before their deaths. The valiant never taste of death but once."
  },{
    id: 2,
    "author": "Steinbeck",
    "source": "East of Eden",
    "quote": "And this I believe: that the free, exploring mind of the individual human is the most valuable thing in the world."
  },{
    id: 3,
    "author": "Vonnegut",
    "source": "Galápagos",
    "quote": "..you are descended from a long line of determined, resourceful, microscopic tadpoles-- champions every one."
  }]
};

var myIndex = 0;
var author = document.getElementById('author');
var source = document.getElementById('source');
var quote = document.getElementById('quote');

//Print first value of array right away.
author.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].author;
source.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].source;
quote.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].quote;

//Generate Tweet with Quote Contents
  function updateTweetURL() {
    var shareQuote = document.getElementById('shareQuote');
    shareQuote.href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + data.quotes[myIndex].quote + ' - ' + data.quotes[myIndex].author ;
  }
  updateTweetURL();

// Action when 'Next Quote' is clicked
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {

  //Load next Quote
function nextElement() {
  updateTweetURL();
  author.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].author;
  source.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].source;
  quote.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].quote;
  myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(data.quotes.length);
};

  nextElement();
});

// Action when Twitter Share is clicked
// document.getElementById('shareQuote').addEventListener("click", function() {
//   //Generate Tweet with Quote Contents
//   function updateTweetURL() {
//     var shareQuote = document.getElementById('shareQuote');
//     shareQuote.href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + data.quotes[myIndex].quote + ' - ' + data.quotes[myIndex].author ;
//   }
//   updateTweetURL();
// });
```

The quotes load properly, clicking on the twitter share button generates the correct share template. However, on the very first time clicking on the "Next Quote" button, it has to be clicked twice to get to the next quote. Thereafter, it is only one click. Any help is appreciated.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/lookininward/pen/gRaydQ)

Comment: var myIndex=1 ... Youre already setting the 0 values on load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, on the very first time clicking on the "Next Quote" button, it has to be clicked twice to get to the next quote.

That's because you're updating `myIndex` at the end of the function `nextElement()`.

You should do that as first step

```
function nextElement() {
  myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(data.quotes.length);  // <----------
  updateTweetURL();
  author.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].author;
  source.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].source;
  quote.innerHTML = data.quotes[myIndex].quote;
};
```

Comment: It's always the little things. Thank you!